# Error with MySQL View in Angular9 Backend

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, typescript, backend

I have a Backend developed in Angular9. This connects to a DB in MySQL in which it makes queries to Tables and Views. Local on my Windows PC works fine. On a Debian server it throws me an error that it cannot find the view, the view exists and from MySQL it works fine.

```
 "result": null,
"err": null,
"message": {
    "body": {
        "code": "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE",
        "errno": 1146,
        "sqlMessage": "Table 'piab_database.pre_license_view' doesn't exist",
        "sqlState": "42S02",
        "index": 0,
        "sql": "SELECT * FROM `pre_license_view`"
    },
    "status": 500,
    "message": "Ha ocurrido un error en su peticion"
```

What could cause this error? Greetings and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the code work in windows but on in Unix/Linux (debian)  this mean you have some problem with uppercase/lowercase name of a file or tablename  check for exact case matching between the two env.

```
 Table 'piab_database.pre_license_view'
```

could be you view name contain uppercase chars

Comment: But the tables like piab_database.company_table work. Only *_view dont work. I dont know why.

Comment: then check if the view name on LINUX contain  one or more Uppercas chars

Comment: I try te name in lowcase, together and short name and the problem is not that. I think is the mariadb or something.

Answer (score 0):

Good Solved ... It turns out that the user with whom I was connecting to the db was admin but for some reason I did not have permission on views and that is why I did not see them ... create a user with only local access for that database only (a recommended practice) and that I give all the permissions on this .. I hope you solve the problem for others ... greetings ...